# javascript .substr breaks alert method

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to pull the hours and minutes out of a Microsoft JSON string. I've gone through several articles, the most recent one being: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date) to no avail. When I try to follow the example code provided.

The alert won't fire. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing. The pertinent code is here:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/TrainActivity/GetDelayDataForEditing/" + "?delayId=" + delId,
  dataType: 'json',
  //data: delId,
  success: function(data) {
    //data = JSON.stringify(data);
    //$("#myDivID").text(JSON.stringify(data));
    //var delayId = delId;

    modal.find('');
    //This is my code based off stack overflow article, and it breaks the alert
    var date = new Date(parseInt(data.beginDelayDateTime.substr(6)));

    //var date = data.beginDelayDateTime.substr(6);
    //var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));

    //this date is okay
    //var date = new Date();
    var unparsedDate = moment(data.beginDelayDateTime);
    var parsedDate = new Date(unparsedDate);
    var hours = parsedDate.getHours;
    var minutes = parsedDate.getMinutes;
    var timeToDisplay = hours + ":" + minutes;
    //var timeToDisplay = JSON.stringify(hours) + ":" + JSON.stringify(minutes);

    alert("Success " +
      //"\ntest date: " + date +
      "\nunparsed date: " + unparsedDate +
      "\nParsed date: " + parsedDate +
      "\nDisplay time: " + timeToDisplay +
      "\nbegin Delay time: " + data.BeginDelayDateTime
    );

    //$('#delays-grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    //$("#delayAddModal").modal("hide");

  },
  error: function() {
    alert("error in Delay Edit");
  }
});

//modal.find(".modal-body").text("Edit the Delay at " + name + " with id " + delId);
modal.find(".modal-footer #delayEditButton").data("guid", delId);
});
```

data.beginDelayDateTime has /Date(1531958520000)/ in it and that value ("/Date(1531958520000)/") displays in the alert with no problems.

Comment: So what is the error in the developer console?

Comment: If the alert doesnt fire, there is probably an error inbetween.

Comment: You never set the variable `jsonDate`.

Comment: Please don't comment out the code that you're asking about. SO's syntax highlighting makes it hard to read.

Comment: The problem is most likely with parseInt failure. First examine the contents of `jsonDate` and then `jsonDate.substr`. Verify that the string returned by `jsonDate.substr` contains only numbers.

Comment: In the question you link to, `jsonDate` is the parameter to the `formatJSONDate()` function. You copied the variable name, but not the function, so the variable has no meaning.

Comment: @Kaushik I'm not using jsonDate. I'm using data.BeginDelayDateTime.

Comment: @Barmar I uncommented the problematic code.

Comment: The question says that when you try to use `var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));` the alert doesn't fire. That's using `jsonDate`.

Comment: @epascarello The console give me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined at Object.success

Comment: So what is the error message....

Comment: Okay now with that edit, so right there it is undefined so you are reading the property wrong.... `data.xxxxxxxx` is not defined. So debug what data is. `console.log(data)`

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure what that means "so you are reading the property wrong"

Comment: The property is undefined so that means `data` does not have what you think it does. Log the message, see what you have....

Comment: @epascarello how do I log the message?

Comment: What I put in my comment

Comment: @epascarello okay

Comment: @epascarello So I added: console.log(data) to my jquery function (just before the "var date..." and I get BeginDelayDateTime:"/Date(1531992480000)/" Which is the same value that I was getting in the alert.

Comment: BeginDelayDateTime != beginDelayDateTime

Comment: @epascarello You're exactly right. That was my error: typo. :-/ Thank you for your help. How should I mark the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by correcting a typographical error. As epascarello pointed out BeginDelayDateTime != beginDelayDateTime. By correcting the misspelling, the issue was resolved an the Microsoft JSON date string is being parsed correctly. Many thanks to all who contributed their help.